ROS2 multicast a topic to remote machines
I understand that the when using RTPS protocol multicast is used to discover other nodes on the network, I am wondering if it is also possible to multicast topics to a private network?
In my setup I have 3 PCs (ROS2 humble installed on all of them) all of them connected to a single switch and a single ethernet camera connected to the same switch. I use one of the PCs as a server where I start a ROS2 camera node and I subscribe to the topics on the other 2 PCs.
It works as expected, the server sends the desired data to the 2 remote PCs.
The nodes get discovered and the data is sent in a way:
IP_server -> IP_remote1
IP_server -> IP_remote2.
My question is is there a way to do:
IP_server -> multicast_addr,
multicast_addr -> IP_remote1,
multicast_addr -> IP_remote2 ?
I'm asking this since in case where all of the remotes need to subscribe to the same topics the server needs to send the topic data to each of the remotes individually which increases the bandwidth used, whereas if the server could multicast the topic data the remotes could still subscribe to it but bandwidth used would be much smaller.
